# How to get path to installed Visual Studio 15 Preview 4?

Tags: registry, visual-studio-2017

Visual Studio 14.0 (2015) installer saves path to devenv.exe to EnvironmentPath in registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Setup\vs\
```

Visual Studio 15 Preview 4 does not save EnvironmentPath to HKLM registry. What is proper way to get executable path of installed Visual Studio 15?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Visual Studio "15" you should use the new setup configuration API to discover installed instances of Visual Studio with different workloads. See [Visual Studio Setup Configuration Samples](https://github.com/microsoft/vs-setup-samples) for the sample code.