# How to find VS 15 Preview 5 is installed or not by checking registry?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

How to find whether Visual Studio 15 preview 5 is installed or not by checking registry entry?

**Note:** In VS 2015 installed machine, I have found out below registry for checking whether VS 2015 is installed or not.

**Registry Location :** HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0

**Key Value:** InstallDir

Could you please share how to get the install location for VS15 preview 5 from registry location or by programatically?

Comment: That's the wrong way to check for any installed program. If anything, it will fail on a 32-bit machine. `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` is where all *installed* programs appear

Comment: Your method will fail on 32-bit machines You should check `SOFTWARE\Microsoft`... not the mirror hive. You'll find that there *is* a `15.0` key there if VS 15 is installed

Comment: And please, don't use unrelated tags. Did you look for the `15.0` key? Did you check for `InstallDir` under it? Why ask at all when you already know that the current version appears in `14.0`? Do you have a *different* problem? Do you think that `15.0` contains the wrong information? Or are you asking for `Preview 5` specifically?

Comment: I am asking for Visual Studio "15" Preview 5.

  I have edited registry location as like below in this post.
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0.

I have checked HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0 registry in VS 15 Preview 5 installed machine.But unable to find InstallDir Value.

Comment: Why are you looking for that specific value? The `15.0` key exists both in `WOW5432Node` and in `SOFTWARE\Microsoft...`. That key isn't an indicator that something is installed anyway - the installed programs appear in the `Uninstall` key

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to write your own installer for something? Perhaps create an extension that targets multiple VS editions?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39795355/how-to-get-path-to-installed-visual-studio-15-preview-4

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio "15" will no longer be registered in the machine registry hive.  Mostly this is because VS "15" will allow you to install multiple instances on your machine; the registry would only be able to point to one of them using the previous schema.

Instead, there is a new API available to query the install status.  See [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2016/09/15/changes-to-visual-studio-15-setup/) for a description of the changes, and it links to [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/microsoft/vs-setup-samples) for samples of how to use the new package.